# Get fullpath from requestContext RESTEasy3.0.7 PreRequestFilter for Security in JAVA

Tags: java, resteasy

I am working on RESTEasy3.0.7 PreRequestFilter to make my REST API secure. Here I am trying to get fullpath as mentioned in screen short which is available in methodInvoker. There is no direct method to get this value.. I have tried using getProperty but it also not worked.

```
@Provider
public class PreRequestFilter implements javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter
{
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException 
    {
        ResourceMethodInvoker methodInvoker = (ResourceMethodInvoker) requestContext.getProperty("org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker");
        Method method = methodInvoker.getMethod();
```

[image]

I just need methodInvoker -> method -> fullpath value.. can anyone help in this regard like how can get this value if there is no method available directly..

Comment: Do you need the template including ```{requestId}``` or the requested path with a replaced requestId?

Comment: Hi Lefloh, Yes i need template which includes {requestId} like in above fullpath i.e. /status/1.0/box/peripheral/request/{requestId}

Comment: The other thing would be easy. I don't know a direct way. You could replace the templates back on the requested URI. Or you could concat the path segments yourself from the ```@Path``` values. Both not nice.

Comment: Yes both are not nice but I have to go with some mechanism until unless i will find the proper way.

Answer (score 3):

Obtaining the requested path can be done easily:

```
String path = requestContext.getUriInfo().getPath();
```

But I don't know a standard-way to get the URI-Template without substituted path parameters. The `ResourceMethodInvoker` is only exposing the `java.lang.reflect.Method` of the `org.jboss.resteasy.spi.metadata.ResourceMethod` but not the `org.jboss.resteasy.spi.metadata.ResourceMethod` itself which you need to access.

You could get the template per reflection:

```
Field field = ResourceMethodInvoker.class.getDeclaredField("method");
field.setAccessible(true);
ResourceMethod method = (ResourceMethod) field.get(methodInvoker);
String path = method.getFullpath();
```